# Setting Apache mod_headers while we access directory any directory?

Tags: apache, mod-headers

I am using apache 2.2. I have to set header for home page url only. e.g If url is https://www.example.com then I need to set header for this URL only. Could you please help me on this?

I have tried below things but no luck.

1. If condition used but not working for this version.
2. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} / 
   Header set ABC "abc" 
   Here, Header is setting for all URLs in the application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using mod\_rewrite to redirect home page ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038533/using-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-home-page-only)

Comment: Yes Joe, I am trying to add header while redirection. Do you have any input on header part?